# If n $\geq2$, does G necessarily have an element of order $p^2$? Justify your answer.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If n $\geq2$, does a group G of order $p^n$ necessarily have an element of order $p^2$? Justify your answer.

p is a prime number.
n is an integer.

I can't seem to find a counterexample, but I think it is false.

Comment: What is $G$, what is $p$?

Comment: Also, what is $n$?

Comment: That $n$ and $p$ just has no relationship with $G$?

Comment: To be more precise: What are the relations between $G$, $p$ and $n$?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>My guess is that $G$ is a group, $p$ is a prime number dividing $n$, and $n$ is the order of the group $G$.</strike>  (not true, but close; the counterexample still works)

Consider $G = \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$. Then $G$ has order $4=2^2$, but it has no element of order $p^2$ (the only possible choice of $p$ is $2$).

Comment: sorry for the lack of information. i have edited my post

Comment: Your guess is wrong ^^.

Comment: @John Yes, but the counterexample still works :)

Comment: Ar..... You are right!

Answer (score 1):

The group $C_p \times \cdots \times C_p$ has no element of order $p^2$. In fact, all nontrivial elements have order $p$.